# Generate PDF dynamically with database content

Tags: .net, pdf-generation

I am generating a PDF file which is 5 pages and all the data are coming from Sqlserver. The PDF contains lot of images,watermark and the number sections has to controled dynamically based on database data. What is the best way to generate PDF.i am debating with Crystal report,MSRS[sometimes it requires Activex installation,which is done only by Admin],Itextsharp ,telerik ??? Any suggestion would help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I've had good success with MSRS(local reports) although crystal reports have more formats to export to IIRC.
I remember using Itextsharp once and I think you might come into a problem depending on the version of Adobe reader installed, but you'd have to see that for yourself.

As for MSRS, yes you have to install it but once off like Crystal Reports.

I didn't create dynamically created reports, I used a "template" but if you're talking about dynamically created tables then I think the best would be to test one report first, with both CReports and MSRS and see the output.If you have to do many reports then I'd understand why you need dynamic creation, I didn't but will definitely look into it since it's a mission to have to resize columns,run and print and re do that again and again until it fits.

I even came across problems like half of the row was printed at the bottom of the page..just sharing my experience.

Comment: thanks for ur suggestions.I do have a non-editabe template ,but how to match the column values from Database dataset.I have started with Crystal reports.Let me see how it comes.